# Deleted launch screen view controller and cannot create new one in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have deleted my launch screen view controller by mistake so I am unable to edit the launch screen. I created a new launch view controller, however the old deleted one is still being presented as opposed to the new one. How can I go about wiping all record of the old launch view controller or forcing the new one to display instead of the old one?
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Select your project in the left sidebar, and under the "General" tab, set the "Launch Screen File" to your new file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file and create new File ... select  LaunchScreen and go with it.. .
under project navigator select root file (the project)

in General .. select Launch Screen File .
Here you go.

Answer (score -1):

Select your project file in the left sidebar, under `General Tab` set your newly added `Launch Screen File`.

For more help see below image.

[image]